# Bootstrap Navbar with React

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm very new to React and I'm trying to get the navigation menu down with Bootstrap. I started with create-react-app and I can't seem to get it any functionality of a Bootstrap menu to work.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';
import { Navbar, NavItem, NavDropdown, MenuItem, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
    <div className="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-collapse">
        <span className="icon-bar"></span>
        <span className="icon-bar"></span>
        <span className="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a className="navbar-brand" href="https://www.google.com">Product Shoppe</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="navbar">

    </div>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The current output looks like this:

[image]

I've followed this tut but it doesn't look anything like what is produced in the video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUKJA6B1Xr4&t=969s

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: There's no distinguishable navbar and the hamburger icon doesn't appear on small screens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you imported 'react-bootstrap', you are able to use the react components that it provided.

In order to get a bootstrap navbar working with a basic create-react-app I did the following:

`create-react-app stackoverflow`
`cd stackoverflow`
`yarn add react-bootstrap`

**index.html**
At the end of `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Navbar, NavItem, NavDropdown, MenuItem, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <Navbar>
          <Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Brand>
              <a href="#home">React-Bootstrap</a>
            </Navbar.Brand>
          </Navbar.Header>
          <Nav>
            <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">
              Link
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">
              Link
            </NavItem>
            <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
              <MenuItem eventKey={3.1}>Action</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem eventKey={3.2}>Another action</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem eventKey={3.3}>Something else here</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem divider />
              <MenuItem eventKey={3.4}>Separated link</MenuItem>
            </NavDropdown>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

`yarn start`

[site preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNEXP.png)

[react-bootstrap documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction)

Answer (score 5):

Just in case someone stumble upon this issue of loading a navbar with React-Bootstrap 
first install the package

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

after the package is install go to your .js file component where you want to create the navbar and import it

```
import { Navbar, NavItem, NavDropdown, MenuItem, Nav, Form, FormControl, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

this should do the trick
Example of a React-Bootstrap Navbar

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navbar, NavItem, NavDropdown, MenuItem, Nav, Form, FormControl, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

const Menu = () =>{
    return (
     <div className='App tc f3'>
        <Navbar bg='light' expand='lg'>
          <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Menu</Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className='mr-auto'>
              <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
              <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Divider />
                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
              </NavDropdown>
            </Nav>
            <Form inline>
              <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" />
              <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
            </Form>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    );
}

export default Menu;
```

The final result depends on your design and liking you install tachyons to further personalize your navbar.

Comment: YESSSSSS - This one worked perfectly and to the point.
2-minute job [thumbs up]